# Azure "easy auth" OpenID Connect scope

Tags: authentication, azure-functions, openid-connect

I've tried setting up signaturgruppens eID demo (OIDC) using "Easy auth" in the authentication settings of a .NET function app.

Settings looks like following:
[image]

Metadata URL
https://pp.netseidbroker.dk/op/.well-known/openid-configuration

Client ID
0a775a87-878c-4b83-abe3-ee29c720c3e7

Client Secret
rnlguc7CM/wmGSti4KCgCkWBQnfslYr0lMDZeIFsCJweROTROy2ajEigEaPQFl76Py6AVWnhYofl/0oiSAgdtg==

When I get to the scopes section of this however I get:
[image]

I want to add the scopes "openid nemid mitid" but i can't figure out how and where this portal is?

When trying to access a securet endpoint i also get an error has occured because the scope is invalid:
[image]

So how do i add the scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Use the azure resource explorer (preview):
https://resources.azure.com/

Find the auth2 settings:
subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{rg-name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{app-name}/config/authsettingsV2

Add the scopes in the customOpenIdConnectProviders:
[image]

Comment: you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you